# Custom Control & Toolbox Tab

Tags: c#, user-controls, toolbox

I am creating a user interface and I am trying to figure out the best way to organize all of my custom controls.

I already know that I can do the following:

1) If I want to have a property visible for design-time manipulation via the Properties window, I use the following...

```
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("Text for Display"), Category("Custom Properties")]
    public string DisplayText
    {
        get
        {
            return textDisplay.DisplayText;
        }

        set
        {
            textDisplay.DisplayText = value;
        }
    }
```

2) If I want to hide the control from the Toolbox window, I can use the following...

```
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class TStrategyInput : FlickerControl
{
}
```

The final thing that I am trying to do is to specify the Tab (i.e. category) that my custom control comes up under in the Toolbox window - does anyone have any suggestions?  Are there any other tricks out there for handling custom controls?

Thanks in advance!
William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [MSDN Walkthrough:Autoloading Toolbox Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166237.aspx).

From above:

> The recommended way to add custom controls to the Toolbox is to use
>   the Toolbox Control templates that come with the Visual Studio 10 SDK,
>   which include auto-loading support. This topic is retained for
>   backward compatibility, for adding existing controls to the Toolbox,
>   and for advanced Toolbox development.

Looking at the [Window Forms Toolbox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712575.aspx) that above walkthrough mentions:

```
[ProvideToolboxControl("General", false)]
public partial class Counter : UserControl
```

Comment: Is there no way of doing this aside from creating an entire addon?  It seems like there should be something easier...

Comment: I am not aware of anything, I personally have done everything short of trying to add the control to a specific category and the information I posted was the only thing I was able to find that addressed it.