# Visual Studio extension to add a tab in toolbox for custom controls library

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I have a custom controls library and is looking to develop a Visual Studio 2017 extension to automate the process of adding controls form the library to the toolbox. Provided I get above step working I would like the extension to be more dynamic where a prompt for library file path is asked.
As of now with the appropriate attributes, I can manually add this library to the toolbox and they work.

I have already reviewed reads suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736004/custom-control-toolbox-tab).

Any examples or steps to try to get this working would be appreciated?

Edit: For extension I plan on having a button option "Load [custom] library", on click would have a prompt asking for tab name and path of controls library, which would add a tab in the Toolbox with all controls in the library. Also, a button option to unload library "Unload [custom] library".

Comment: When or what option you want the `add tab`, every time when open a project, automatically do this or do this operation when you click a button from extension.?

Comment: @Lance : I modified my question with my extension requirements.

Comment: That'll be complex, there's no existing example for your requirements. To create a click button or command, see [extending menus and commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-menus-and-commands?view=vs-2017), to get the prompt, see [extend tool windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-and-customizing-tool-windows?view=vs-2017). Then you can execute the code to load the control or unload the control in click-event for the Tool window.

Comment: Thanks @LanceLi-MSFT . Can you point me to an example for loading/unloading custom controls library to toolbox?

Comment: Check if these [two documents about Toolbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-other-parts-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#extend-the-toolbox) can make you some help.

Comment: I have already reviewed these documents, to some extend they were helpful but I am not sure how to supply a library instead of defining my controls in the same project. 
I am experimenting a different route using "EnvDTE(Development Tools Environment)". Suggest if any resources for using EnvDTE.

Comment: Getting Dte object? Using  `DTE dTE=Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57051185/10910450) . More info about the content about EnvDte see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017). (Envdte.DTE)